# Proper punctuation in a sentence with a semicolon

Tags: punctuation, commas, semicolons

Should this comma be included or omitted?

> The resources are rich; the lectures, helpful.

Alternately, is it better to replace the comma with the word "*are*"? (I think it sounds better without the second "*are*".)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your original version.

Comment: Eliezer, I agree with you, it sounds better without the second "are."

Comment: Get rid of the semicolon. _The resources are rich, the lectures helpful._ Punctuation is for long sentences, where you really need it sometimes. In a short sentence you mostly don't, because people can hear the intonation easily.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, but only for certain cases.

> According to [Hagerstown (learning support center) - Basic rules for commas and semicolons](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.hagerstowncc.edu/sites/default/files/documents/Basic%2520Rules%2520for%2520Commas%2520and%2520Semicolons.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwityfOMp9b4AhXkR2wGHa54CGkQFnoECAoQBQ&usg=AOvVaw29JqP8Xr2PJR1uVxhC7HEB):
>
> > Use a semi-colon before the conjunctive adverb (such as however and therefore) that joins two independent clauses. Be sure to put a comma after the conjunctive adverb. **Example: I like working outside; however, I also enjoy reading.**

Note the use of the comma after the semicolon in the example given. The "however" is a conjunctive adverb, and connects the two clauses. Your case is different, where there are two clauses **after** the semicolon, which won't work. So it is best to omit the comma.

> According to [Wikipedia - semiclon](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semicolon):
>
> > In the English language, a semicolon is most commonly used to link two independent clauses that are closely related in thought.

Comment: Which two clauses after the semicolon?

Answer (score -1):

This example involves gapping (here, omitting the second copula):

- *The resources are rich; the lectures are helpful.* →
- *The resources are rich; the lectures, helpful.*

Obviously, the semicolon is the usual choice in the 'original' as there are two independent clauses (though even here, the choice of a comma is not considered unacceptable in some cases, even by respected grammarians).

[Nordquist at ThoughtCo](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-gapping-1690885) gives two credible examples:

> - *The cars were old-fashioned; the buses, too.*
>
> (Bill Bryson, The Life and Times of the Thunderbolt Kid. Broadway Books, 2006)
>
> - *Arnaud was his closest friend; Peter, his oldest.*
>
> (James Salter, Light Years. Random House, 1975)

But the 'retained' semicolon is not the only type of punctuation Nordquist mentions; he gives the example

- *John likes coffee and Susan — tea.*

where the dash codes visually rather well for the deleted verb.

I personally find

- *The resources are rich, the lectures helpful.*

less staccato / cluttered than the semicolon + gapping comma version ... *and it's perfectly understandable*. If not given local constraints (editors, institutional tsars etc) it would be my choice, even though some might object that it violates a pet traditional  rule.

[Jackendoff in *Gapping and Related Rules*](https://babel.ucsc.edu/%7Ehank/jackendoff_related_rules.pdf) does not consider the following ungrammatical:

> - (i) b. *Ivan plays krummhorn, Boris fluegelhorn, and Schwarz
>   bassethorn.*

[British Museum descriptions of exhibits](https://www.britishmuseum.org/collection/object/H_1987-0609-1) tend to exercise flexibility in pinctuation:

> - Inkstand; ... *the base is gold, the shields
>   red and gold on a green ground*; the lid is black, with the relief in
>   several colours ....

(emphasis mine to highlight relevant gapped string)

I'd say

- *The resources are rich, the lectures helpful, and the staff very friendly.*

would raise few hackles. Just a little more padding.